# How to add Time field in models database in odoo 15?

Tags: time, odoo, odoo-15

In Py

```
time = fields.Float('Time')
```

in views

```
<field name="time" widget="float_time"/>
```

the above method is not working as when I try to record time format such 10:50,It shows invalid error message. In order to save the window after editing, I have to record time format in float like 10.50 but when saving, it appears in the report 10:39 in time format.

Another problem when I import excel sheet consists of time, It show me an error that i can not import
[second error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apk7u.png)[third error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdb0g.png)
 error image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd5c9.png)

Comment: Hi, I tried here with 10:50 as input and I could not produce the error. It is working in my end. Can you please send the error message when you try with 10:50 format input?

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because you used the wrong field (you didn't define the `float_time` widget).

You just need to use the [float_time](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/fr/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#non-relational-fields) widget in the XML definition.

***Example:***

```
<field name="field_name" widget='float_time'/>
```

Comment: It is not working for the reasons that i have mentioned above as when i record 10.50 in float, it will be converted to 10:39 after saving

Comment: Please provide the error log, it may be helpful

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIc1D.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv41t.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXIyR.png

Comment: The value should be automatically [converted to a float](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9c19460ce7fb1a16cfeed607e474e273f5ce690b/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/fields/field_utils.js#L645-L657). I do not think you used the correct field.